# Yellow cross-shaped LEGO piece ID

Tags: part-identification

I have had this for a while and was wondering what it is.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [Propeller 4 Blade 5 Diameter with Hole for Rotor Holder](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3461) - used in [71 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3461&in=S), but only in 5 in the yellow color you have.

It was produced by LEGO until 1994, and would have fit on [Plate 2x3 with Helicopter Rotor Holder](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3462).

[image]

Together they would have made the rotor of a helicopter, such as in [1469-1 Helicopter Polybag](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=1469-1).

[image]